# Word order in a negative imperative sentence

Tags: grammar

The following are imperative sentences with subjects not omitted. (Emphasis on **verbs**.)

- *Everybody **look***!
- *Nobody **move***!
- *John **sit*** down; the rest of you go home.
- *Somebody **answer*** the phone!
- *You **keep*** out of this!

These are negative imperatives:

- ***Don’t**<sup>V</sup> you<sup>S</sup>* worry.
- It’s a surprise party so ***don’t**<sup>V</sup> anybody<sup>S</sup>* mention it to Jim.
- *You all<sup>S</sup>, **don’t**<sup>V</sup>* move!
- *You<sup>S</sup>, **don’t**<sup>V</sup>* move!
- ***Don’t**<sup>V</sup> you<sup>S</sup>* move!
- *John<sup>S</sup>, **don’t**<sup>V</sup>* speak!
- ***Don’t**<sup>V</sup> John<sup>S</sup>* speak! (← not works)

In a negative imperative sentence having an explicit subject, when does the verb precede the subject, and when does it not? By “when,” I mean it in terms of grammar and meaning ⸺ What kind of subjects can be used in the “Don’t (subject)―” construction, and what kind of subjects in the “(subject) don’t―”? And how would the order affect the overall tone of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion of the *emphatic imperative* in

> [Books for Languages](https://open.books4languages.com/english-b2-grammar/chapter/emphatic-imperative/)
>
> We form the emphatic imperative by using do and the verb in the infinitive form.
>
> For example:
>
> — “All the students of 6th grade, please do stand in line.” = Emphatic imperative do stand used for a polite request.
>
> — “Sir, do sit down please. You are blocking the view.” = Emphatic imperative do sit used for a complaint.

Similarly, we may make an emphatic negative imperative that places the subject first:

In a school class: “John, don’t speak!”

In a bank robbery: “You all, don’t move!”

On a country walk: “Children, don’t eat the berries!”

Comment: It is a possible construction, I see. When does the subject come first and when does it not, and how are they different in meaning? “Don’t, John, speak!” doesn’t make sense while “Don’t you move!” does. There would be some grammatical rules for that.

Comment: “Don’t, John, speak!” takes us away from your original question. It would make sense in the context that John was being questioned and refused to answer, but the speaker refers to that by saying “Don’t (keep quiet) John. Speak (instead)”. Perhaps John’s wife thinks he should admit his crime to the police.

Comment: I mean, it would do make sense in that context, but I was just trying to make up a sentence the same way “Don’t you move!” is phrased, the subject coming after the verb, and show that it doesn’t work for some other subjects, losing its original intention.

Comment: To clarify, my question was asking for what kind of subject lets you use the subject–verb construction in a negative imperative sentence, what kind for the verb–subject, and the difference in tone between the both constructions, if any.

Comment: The usual term for "John" / "you all" / "children" is 'vocative'

Comment: I agree with BillJ: "John" / "you all" / "children" are not the subjects. The subject remains the unstated "you".